# Is It possible if I will not add product in Magento2 database?

Tags: magento2, module, webapi

Is It possible if I will not add product in Magento2 database , or maybe add product ID attribute for identify the existence in Magento2 system only but I will call API to get product from third party app. and It still can use Magento2 default module such as add to cart or checkout?